# How does the Immovable Object spell (from Explorer's Guide to Wildemount) work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The description of the [*immovable object*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/immovable-object) spell (*Explorer's Guide to Wildemount*, p. 187) says:

> You touch an object that weighs no more than 10 pounds and cause it to become magically fixed in place. You and the creatures you designate when you cast this spell can move the object normally. [...]
>
> If the object is fixed in the air, it can hold up to 4,000 pounds of weight. [...]

So does this mean that to the caster can move the object at will, and wherever he lets go, the object just sits there (in 3-dimensional space)?

or

Can the caster place the object in the air and swing on it or climb using the "immovable" aspect himself? If so, is it a free action to activate, since no action is listed here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes and Yes.  The cases aren't mutually exclusive.

Both the described moving the object by the caster to be fixed in it's new position and using the fixed nature of the object are available to the caster.

### Caster moves the object, it still remains under effect of the spell.

Moving the object does not end the effect of the spell.  So the effects still apply in that the object is fixed in place for everyone but the caster.

### The caster and designees move the object at their discretion.

The use of "can" does not obligate the caster to move the object normally.  This interpretation hinges on the term [can](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can).  In short, the sense of "can" applicable here indicates ability to do a thing and indicating possibility to do it.  The sense here is synonymous with "may".

Contrast the existing wording with that where "can" has been removed. It would essentially be "You move the object normally" indicating the spell effects do not apply to the caster.  The use of "can" gives the caster the option to use the effects of the spell or move the object normally.

Comment: So hypothetically, arrows with this property would be fired as normal by my character, then once they embed themselves into a creature that creature would have their movement impaired until they could back off the arrow?  Or if a wall was behind them, they would be pinned there?
(English is my 3rd lang, I am just trying to make sure I have it right)

Comment: @SamLacrumb I do not believe so. Generally, the archer aims an arrow and lets the bow do the work of moving it.  This would be an application for a dagger or other implement the caster was themselves moving.

Comment: @SamLacrumb No, you let go off the arrow and it can't move anymore, so it can't even move away from you at all.